# Deixar divs fluidas

Tags: css3

tenho a seguinte estrutura

```
<div id="container-header">
  <div class="center">

    <div class="content-header">content-header</div>
    <div class="thumb-header">thumb-header</div>

  </div>
</div>


div {width: 100%;}

.center {
   width: 71.42857142857143%;/*1200/1680*/
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.center > div {
   height: 120px;
   background-color: #ccc;
}

.content-header {width: 83.33333333333333%;/*1000/1200*/}

.thumb-header {width: 14.33333333333333%;/*172/1200*/}
```

**resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora quando diminuo a tela a div `thumb-header` perde seu tamanho normal, nesse caso teria que fazer uma `media queries` pra cada situação ou tem outro jeito?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com " tamanho normal", na verdade o tamanho dela está normal, ela corresponde ao tamanho que vc delimitou 14.3% da largura do pai... quanto menor o pai, visualmente menor vão ficando os filhos... Qual comportamento vc queria que eles tivessem?

Comment: @hugocsl opa hugo, tipo queria que a `thumb-header` acompanhasse a tela só que mantesse a aparencia de `14.3%` entendeu? exemplo http://prntscr.com/nwc4tj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem vc quer que tenha 14.3% da largura, mas tb quer que respeite uma largura mínima, para isso vc vai ter que usar um `min-width`. Por exemplo se a tela for bem larga o tamanho fica em 14.3%, mas se for bem pequena ela vai ter um mínimo de 160px de largura por exemplo... E a div da direita vc deixa com `flex:1` assim ela só vai ocupar o espaça restante

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
div {border: 1px solid #000;}

.center {
    width: 71.42857142857143%;/*1200/1680*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

.center > div {
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.content-header {
  flex: 1;
  /* espaço entre uma div e outra */
  margin-right: 16px; 
  }

.thumb-header {
  width: 14.33333333333333%;/*172/1200*/
  min-width: 160px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container-header">
  <div class="center">

    <div class="content-header">content-header</div>
    <div class="thumb-header">thumb-header ratione rem consequatur.</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: como sempre salvando minha vida

Comment: @goio Sem problema meu caro []'s